# Создать внешний ключ

Tags: php, mysql

Не  понимаю в чём может быть проблема.
Есть две таблицы. Ниже фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать внешний ключ из таблицы Users на таблицу t_koatuu_tree.

В таблице Users поле territory_id char(10), а в таблице t_koatuu_tree поле ter_id char(10).

Пишу такой запрос

```
ALTER TABLE Users ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tr_id FOREIGN KEY (territory_id) REFERENCES t_koatuu_tree(ter_id);
```

Но выдаёт ошибку (ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
)

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а это полный текст ошибки? возможно в таблице уже имеются данные, у которых колонка пустая, которые должны ссылаться на вторую таблицу. То есть нужно добавить данные в колонку `territory_id`, а потом только добавить foreign key. Либо временно в `users` снять ограничение null, добавить внешний ключ, добавить данные и поставить опять NOT NULL

Comment: посмотрите в `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, там должно быть адекватное описание что именно не так

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение данной проблемы.

Нужно посмотреть кодировку той таблицы, на которую хотите сослаться.
При создании другой таблицы я просто в конце добавил нужную кодировку (чтобы они совпадали):

```
create table Users(
    -> id INT(11) primary key NOT NULL,
    -> fio varchar(255),
    -> email varchar(50),
    -> territory_id char(10) NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

И теперь при добавлении внешнего ключа, всё успешно добавляется :)